# Getting error TokenAuthenticationError while running Benzinga

Tags: python, finance

I want to rates the stocks in Benzinga using Benzinga API for python. But, when I follow its documentation I get an error as shown below.

```
raise TokenAuthenticationError
benzinga.benzinga_errors.TokenAuthenticationError: Error Message: Something went wrong. Please again try again later
```

I used the default key from Benzinga API Document.

```py
from benzinga import financial_data
api_key = "testkey892834789s9s8abshtuy"
fin = financial_data.Benzinga(api_key)

stock_ratings = fin.ratings()
fin.output(stock_ratings)
```

What should I do to make it work? Did the API key is expired and I need to renew it?