# looking for error code documentation for Benzinga API (authentication error)

Tags: python, api

Someone else posted a similar message, but it was never answered on Stackoverflow Ref:
[Getting error TokenAuthenticationError while running Benzinga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536515/getting-error-tokenauthenticationerror-while-running-benzinga).

I am trying to do a simple example as posted on the Benzinga python package site (ref: https://pypi.org/project/benzinga/).

The code is (with api_key changed to prevent theft)

```
 from benzinga import financial_data
 from benzinga import news_data
 api_key="mykey"

 fin=financial_data.Benzinga(api_key,log=False)
 stock_ratings=fin.ratings()
 fin.output(stock_ratings)
```

When running it in Spyder, I get the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Pictures\BenzingaTestNews01.py", line 13, in <module>
     stock_ratings=fin.ratings()

   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\benzinga\financial_data.py", line 511, in ratings
     self.__check_status(ratings.status_code)

   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
     packages\benzinga\financial_data.py", line 83, in __check_status
     raise TokenAuthenticationError
```

TokenAuthenticationError: Error Message: Something went wrong. Please again try again later

When I look at that portion of the code provided by Benzinga in financial_data.py, I see a set of error codes. Can someone point me to documentation that explain what the error codes mean?

```
  def __check_status(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 400:
        raise BadRequestError
    if status_code == 401:
        raise TokenAuthenticationError
    elif status_code == 403:
        raise TokenAuthenticationError
    elif status_code == 404:
        raise NotFoundError
    elif status_code == 412:
        raise PreconditionFailedError
    elif status_code == 429:
        raise RateLimitError
    elif status_code == 500:
        raise ServiceUnavailableError
    elif status_code == 502:
        raise ServiceUnavailableError
    elif status_code == 503:
        raise ServiceUnavailableError
    elif status_code == 504:
        raise GatewayTimeoutError
```